# How can I calculate degree, eigenvector, bonacich power centrality using R igraph package?

Tags: r, igraph, eigenvector, sna

I am trying to calculate degree centrality, eigenvetor centrality and bonacich power centrality using igraph package in R. My data is South Korea's commuting data.

My data looks like this[1st column: orientation region code, 2nd column: destination region code, 3rd column: commuting times between the two regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8urD2.png)

I have made igraph graph using function graph_from_data_frame() like the picture below.
[od18 is the data I used. The same one mentioned at the first picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THpkw.png)
But here are my problems.

1. I can't make an adjacency matrix using this graph.

: Error in get.adjacency.sparse(graph, type = type, attr = attr, edges = edges,  :
Sparse matrices must be either numeric or logical,and the edge attribute is not

[this is the code I executed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vZWM.png)
[this is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdyw7.png)

Actually, I don't care about the adjacency matrix if centrality calculations don't have problems. But I am worrying what if this means that I am not going to get correct results of centrality calculations.

2. I tried to calculate the degree centrality using function degree() but the results values are all same.
   [All of my nodes have the same degree values as 250.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6tgE.png)
3. Any help about Bonacich power centrality using -beta.

Can you help me with these problems?

Comment: Please read how to create a reproducible example so you can get help easier. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As noted by @programandoconro your question does not really provide enough information, but based on what you have shown it appears that all nodes may in fact have a degree of 250.  If you have 250 nodes and there is a nonzero commuting time between all nodes, then all nodes have a degree of 250 (they have a tie to each other node) .  I'm not sure that bonacich power centrality is well defined for this kind of network.  Your issue may have more to do with network measurement than coding.